# Special Layout div square with squares

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I had an idea for a game that I wanted to make in HTML. I just do not know how to create this layout:

[image: This is an approximate layout for my idea.]

How could I achieve this with HTML, JavaScript, and CSS? (No, I am not a n00b. I just do not know how to create a square with little squares.) Many thanks. P.S. I am a kid. :) Also, sorry about the visual. I threw it together in two minutes.

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: provide your HTML and CSS you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a grid layout with columns and rows. This should help you get started.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOMNdo

## HTML

```
<div class="board">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column connector">
      |
    </div>
    <div class="column connector">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="column connector">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="column connector">
      |
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column connector">
      |
    </div>
    <div class="column connector">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="column connector">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="column connector">
      |
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column connector">
      |
    </div>
    <div class="column connector">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="column connector">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="column connector">
      |
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="box">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Option 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.row {
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;width: 150px;
}

.column.connector {
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: from a single select, float, clear and margin you could still sort your rows/column ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could even do this with single select and draw your lines from box-shadow:

```css
select {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 100px 60px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 40px white, 0 -40px 0 40px white, 0 40px 0 40px white, 0 -40px 0 41px, 0 40px 0 41px, 0 0 0 41px;
}
form {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 110px white, inset 0 0 0 111px black;
}
select:nth-child(5),
select:nth-child(7) {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 200px;
  clear: right;
}
select:nth-child(6),
select:nth-child(8) {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
  </select>

  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

boxes can be drawn from a single div wrapping each select, and the lines in between from a pseudo element behind them:

```css
    form {
      padding: 0;
      margin: auto;
      width: 900px;
      background: white;
    }
    form,
    p {
      position: relative;
    }
    form:before {
      content: '';
      border: 1px solid;
      position: absolute;
      top: 110px;
      left: 110px;
      right: 110px;
      bottom: 110px;
      z-index: 0;
    }
    p {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      line-height: 16px;
      padding: 70px 30px;
      margin: 30px;
      border: 1px solid;
      background: inherit;
    }
    p:nth-child(5),
    p:nth-child(7) {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 200px;
      clear: right;
    }
    p:nth-child(6),
    p:nth-child(8) {
      float: right;
      margin-left: 200px;
    }
    select {
      width: 100px;
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <select>
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <select>
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <select>
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <select>
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <select>
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <select>
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <select>
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <select>
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <select>
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <select>
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <select>
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <select>
      <option>Select</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
    </select>
  </p>
</form>
```